# How can I add a POST form on a site with a PATCH form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

At the company I'm working, they asked to translate a form for (POST) creation or (PATCH) update of data, to another site that already has a form that only edits (PATCH) information. Each form is independent, that is to say, each form has its own related controller.

My problem is that I haven't found an example with this complexity with Rails although it doesn't seem as complex, given that each form works independently, but I don't know if Rails architecture allows me to include a POST form of a C1 controller in a view that already has a PATCH form of a C2 controller.

Is it possible to do that?

Ruby 2.5.0
Rails 5.2.1

Comment: Rails supports patch forms (https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#how-do-forms-with-patch-put-or-delete-methods-work-questionmark), maybe you can show your attempt?

Comment: It is possible, just define all needed @variables for a new form.